# Error: failed to run custom build command for `argonautica v0.2.0`

Tags: rust, jwt

I am a rust developer to build the authentication API I want to hashing and verify using the argonautica crate but I was add that crate to my cargo.toml file that will be return the error to me. Can you help how to solve this error?

```
[package]
name = "rust-authentication"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
anyhow = "1.0.81"
chrono = { version = "0.4.35", features = ["serde"] }
clap = "3.0.0-beta.2"
argonautica = "0.2.0"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
jsonwebtoken = "9.3.0"
serde = { version = "1.0.197", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.114"
sqlx = { version = "0.7.4", default-features = false, features = ["macros", "postgres", "uuid", "chrono", "json", "runtime-tokio-rustls"] }
thiserror = "1.0.58"
tokio = { version = "1.36.0", features = ["full"] }
uuid = { version = "1.8.0", features = ["serde", "v4"] }
warp = "0.3.6"


[[bin]]
name = "rust-authentication"
path= "src/main.rs"
```

Error below:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `argonautica v0.2.0`                                                                                                 

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `D:\dev-dhanushkumar\rust-authentication\target\debug\build\argonautica-33ab26df58e3e0fc\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)  
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT
  argon2.c
  core.c
  blake2b.c
  encoding.c
  thread.c
  ref.c
  exit code: 0
  exit code: 0
  exit code: 0
  exit code: 0
  exit code: 0
  exit code: 0
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  AR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  AR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_AR
  HOST_AR = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AR
  AR = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  ARFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  ARFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_ARFLAGS
  HOST_ARFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARFLAGS
  ARFLAGS = None
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=argon2
  cargo:rustc-link-search=native=D:\dev-dhanushkumar\rust-authentication\target\debug\build\argonautica-91468f2bff505b47\out

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at C:\Users\Hitesh Amudhan\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\bindgen-0.48.1\src/lib.rs:1652:31:
  Unable to find libclang: "couldn't find any valid shared libraries matching: ['clang.dll', 'libclang.dll'], set the `LIBCLANG_PATH` environment variable to a path where one of these files can be found (invalid: [])"
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
[Finished running. Exit status: 0]
[Running 'cargo run']
    Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache
    Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache
    Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache
    Blocking waiting for file lock on build directory
   Compiling sqlx-macros-core v0.7.4
   Compiling argonautica v0.2.0
   Compiling warp v0.3.6
error: failed to run custom build command for `argonautica v0.2.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `D:\dev-dhanushkumar\rust-authentication\target\debug\build\argonautica-33ab26df58e3e0fc\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)  
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT
  argon2.c
  core.c
  blake2b.c
  encoding.c
  thread.c
  ref.c
  exit code: 0
  exit code: 0
  exit code: 0
  exit code: 0
  exit code: 0
  exit code: 0
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  AR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  AR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_AR
  HOST_AR = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AR
  AR = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  ARFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  ARFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_ARFLAGS
  HOST_ARFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ARFLAGS
  ARFLAGS = None
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=argon2
  cargo:rustc-link-search=native=D:\dev-dhanushkumar\rust-authentication\target\debug\build\argonautica-91468f2bff505b47\out

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at C:\Users\Hitesh Amudhan\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\bindgen-0.48.1\src/lib.rs:1652:31:
  Unable to find libclang: "couldn't find any valid shared libraries matching: ['clang.dll', 'libclang.dll'], set the `LIBCLANG_PATH` environment variable to a path where one of these files can be found (invalid: [])"
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

I want solve this error successfully build the cargo file in my project.

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems to be the relevant error message: Unable to find libclang: "couldn't find any valid shared libraries matching: ['clang.dll', 'libclang.dll'], set the `LIBCLANG_PATH` environment variable to a path where one of these files can be found (invalid: [])"

Comment: And here are the relevant docs – looks like you need to install clang as described on that page: https://docs.rs/argonautica/latest/argonautica/#installation